# How do I get asp.net 3.5 validator messages to take up space in a form only when displayed?

Tags: asp.net, forms, asp.net-3.5

My form in asp.net 3.5 is set up inside an html table, and is rendering with enough space to display all the validator error messages attached to the textboxes, checkboxes, etc. in each row.

My table is 3 columns, with column one labeling each control, column 2 holding the controls themselves, and column 3 being reserved for the validator controls. Column 3 is pushing the whole row to be taller when I have a longer error message, and makes the form elements display with an odd spacing in between them.

I'd like to have a more uniform look to the form elements, but also need to keep some of the longer validator error messages.

How do I get the form to display without the extra spaces and adjust only when the message actually needs to be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have your validators set to use a [Display property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksfy5wzx.aspx) of Dynamic?  This will allow them to only be shown when needed.